# How does one satisfy a predicate with a boolean condition

Tags: java, predicate

I'm trying to iterate over a list to satisfy a boolean condition and then finally append that to an array. I'm not really sure if theres another way of doing this but I'm totally stuck and can't really find anything about my issue. Here's a snippet of the code:

So what im trying to do is say if `isCryDamage` is `true` for any of the `entities` I want to append that `BlockPos` to `filteredPositions`. I would know how to do this in py but i dont really know whats going on in Java with this predicate business. At the moment its saying `CrystalUtils.GetPlayerPosFloored(entity))` needs to be a predicate type.

```
List<EntityPlayer> entities = mc.world.playerEntities;
List<BlockPos> sufficientBlocks = CrystalUtils.findCrystalBlocks((int) range.getValDouble());
List<BlockPos> filteredPositions = new ArrayList<>();
for (EntityPlayer entity : entities) {
    sufficientBlocks.stream().filter(isCryDamageSufficient(CrystalUtils.GetPlayerPosFloored(entity))).forEach(filteredPositions::add);
}

public static boolean isCryDamageSufficient(final BlockPos enemy){
    return calculateDamage(enemy.getX(), enemy.getY(), enemy.getZ(), mc.player) > minDam.getValDouble();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

filter method(`Stream<T> filter(Predicate<? super T> predicate);`) need a `Predicate` as parameter,try to modify you loop code as follow:

```java
for (EntityPlayer entity : entities) {
    sufficientBlocks.stream().filter(blockPos -> isCryDamageSufficient(blockPos)).forEach(filteredPositions::add);
}
```